# Why does a newline digraph in a macro get interpreted as a `j` in Vim?

Tags: vim, digraphs

Let's say I create a macro that goes down one line.

`qajq`

Register `a` contains exactly `qajq`, and so `@a` moves me down one line.

Now let's say I type `j` into my buffer and yank it into register `a` using `"ayy`. Now, register `a` looks like `j^J` (notice the terminal newline digraph). Now, when I execute the macro `a`, it jumps down two lines.

What exactly is happening here? Does Vim see the `^J` digraph and think that I want to go down an extra line, or is it something more subtle?

I guess this is one of those questions where the answer is, "because that's how it was designed." :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you type `qajq` the `a` register content is the string `j`. `qa` starts recording the macro into register `a`, then you type `j` and  it's the first character recorder, now you type `q` and vim stops recording. So, you end up with just `j` in the register `a`.

The command `yy` works linewise, so the newline is also inserted into the register. When you type `"ayy` you end up with `j^J` in the `a` register because `^J` or `Ctrl-J` (a line feed) is what vim uses to represent the newline, and it also moves the cursor one line down as described in `:help Ctrl-J`

In order to yank the line without the newline you can type `0"ay$`. That would be the same as typing `qajq`.

Comment: My whole question really amounted to your sentence about Ctrl-J. Didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't make sure what happen on your vim. But I'd say what vim should work as right behavior.

You type `qajq`. So motion `j` is registered into register `a`. And you seems type `yy` to register something into register `a`. But As far as I know, it register into register `"` not register `a`. To yank something into register `a`, you should type `"ayy`. It's possible to confirm with `:register` command. Maybe something wrong typing?

Comment: That was a typo. It's fixed now.